# Giving a select option more than one _post value

Tags: php

I am changing the header of my php mail form so that it shows who it was sent from. I have a  with contact name options. I want to give those options two values so that I can query on value in one location and the second in another. I feel like the values have to be assigned to a differnt select names to be able to query it, but I have no clue how to go about doing it. Example:

PHP Form

```
 Contact: 
 <select name="contactname">
 <option></option>
 <option value1="John Smith" value2="jsmith@email.com">John Smith</option>
 </select>
```

PHP Post

```
$contactname = $_POST [contactname];

$header = "From: " . $value 1 here . " <" . $value 2 here . ">\r\n";

$message = "

Contact: $value 1 here
";


mail("email.email.com", $subject, $message, $header,);
```

Anyone have any ideas how to code what I trying to get?

Comment: Couldn't you just make an array, separating by a comma then exploding it to unique variables?

Answer (score 3):

If the list of options is coming out of a database, put in the table's primary key value instead, and then you can look up the appropriate values when the form's submitted. That saves you the hassle of having to validate the email addresses, because nothing says a malicious user can't hack up the script to say "president@whitehouse.gov" and put some threats in the message. They sent the message, but you're the one who'll have the Secret Service kicking down your door.

Comment: This is a much better solution than what has been suggested, and is the "right way".  I am not confident that the OP will be able to take this advice and implement it, but this is definitely what I would do if it were my project! +1

Comment: No kiddin! Thanks for looking out. Do you know how to quicky lock up the "view source" on IE?

Comment: You can't. At most you can pop up a window with the menus hidden, and try to disable the right-click context menu, but those are just bandaids. If someone wants to view the html, they will.

Comment: Ok so i tried to do your code and i got this on the post page: parse error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<select name="contactname">
<option value="John Smith|jsmith@email.com">John Smith</option>
</select>
```

PHP

```
$pieces = explode('|', $_POST['contactname']);

$from = $pieces[0]; // John Smith
$to = $pieces[1]; // jsmith@email.com
```

Note that this isn't actually the proper way since it can be spoofed.

Answer (score 1):

Contact:

```
<select name="contactname">
    <option></option>
    <option value="John Smith,jsmith@email.com">John Smith</option>
</select>
```

PHP

```
$contactname = $_POST['contactname'];

$contact_arr = explode(",", $contactname);

$header = "From: ".$contact_arr[0]." <".$contact_arr[1].">";

$message = "

Contact: ".$contact_arr[0]."

";

mail("email@email.com", $subject, $message, $header);
```

Explode and a delimiter will do it. You should really run some validation on $_POST to make sure its clean first though.

Comment: Thanks BEN! I'm not running it out of a DB so this is the sultion i was looking for!

Comment: Ok so i tried to do your code and i got this on the post page: parse error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: how can i show you the page code? do i have to start a new Question?